# How do you get the physical drive number of a removable device from the drive letter in Windows 7?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, windows-7

I'm trying to look up the physical drive number (as in, I need the `N` in `\\.\PhysicalDriveN` to open the block device for reading) from the drive letter of a CDROM drive on Windows 7. [This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676078%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) indicates that IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER should work, but it returns 0 for the drive number for both C: and D: (where D: is the removable drive), so that can't be right. IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS is also suggested, but that fails with an ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION on D:.

I can't help but feel that I've missed a crucial concept somewhere.

Here's my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Windows.h"


void printLastError(){
  DWORD lastError;
  DWORD bytesReturned;
  WCHAR outbuf[2048];

  lastError = GetLastError();

  bytesReturned = FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,
    NULL, lastError, LANG_USER_DEFAULT, outbuf, 2048, NULL);

  if (bytesReturned > 0){
    wprintf(outbuf);
  } else {
    printf("Error %d while formatting error %d\n", GetLastError(),     lastError);
  }
}

void readDeviceNumberByExtents(HANDLE hFile){
  BOOL ioctlSuccess;
  DWORD bytesReturned;

  VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS vde;

  ioctlSuccess = DeviceIoControl(hFile,
    IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS,
    NULL, 0, &vde, sizeof(vde), &bytesReturned, NULL);

    if (ioctlSuccess != 0){
      printf("%d\n", vde.Extents->DiskNumber );
    } else {
      printLastError();
  }
}

void readDeviceNumberByStorage(HANDLE hFile){
  BOOL ioctlSuccess;
  DWORD bytesReturned;

  STORAGE_DEVICE_NUMBER sdn;

  ioctlSuccess = DeviceIoControl(hFile,
    IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER,
    NULL, 0, &sdn, sizeof(sdn), &bytesReturned, NULL);

  if (ioctlSuccess != 0){
    printf("%d\n", sdn.DeviceNumber );
  } else {
    printLastError();
  }
}

void runTest(WCHAR* driveName){
  HANDLE driveHandle;
  DWORD diskNumber;

  driveHandle = CreateFile(driveName,
    0,
    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
    NULL);

  if (driveHandle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
    wprintf(L"Opened %s\n", driveName);

    printf("Device number by extents: ");
    readDeviceNumberByExtents(driveHandle);
    printf("Device number by storage: ");
    readDeviceNumberByStorage(driveHandle);

    CloseHandle(driveHandle);
  } else {
    printf("Failure!\n");   
  }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  runTest(L"\\\\.\\C:");
  printf("\n");
  runTest(L"\\\\.\\D:");

  getc(stdin);
  return 0;
}
```

...and the output when I run it, either as Administrator or not:

```
Opened \\.\C:
Device number by extents: 0
Device number by storage: 0

Opened \\.\D:
Device number by extents: Incorrect function.
Device number by storage: 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `"\\.\PhysicalDriveN"` only works for (things that act like) hard drives, not removable disks. If something acts like a removable disk (or floppy, CD-ROM, etc.), `"\\.\X:"` opens the raw drive (other drives don't support partitions, so the distinction between `"\\.\x:"` and `"\\.\PhysicalDiskN"` doesn't exist for them). You normally want to use `GetDriveType` to figure out what kind of disk you have, and only if that says it's a `DRIVE_FIXED` do you attempt to find the drive number and use `"\\.\PhysicalDriveN"` with it.

Comment: Ah-ha! That seems to be the crucial concept :-)

Comment: Is that strictly true, I need raw access to a USB Drive (which is of removable type), but opening \\.\X: only gives me the first partition on the USB drive - I am searching for a way to map from X:\ to \\.\PhysicalDriveX and looks like if this does work, it's my answer

Comment: Could you please show me the source where you read that no \\.\PhysicalDriveX created for removable devices? I built upon this assumption, and now I have a bug, and have to redesign this part of the software, because it seems Windows creates \\.\PhysicalDriveX entries for USB pen drives, leaving gaps in the numbering when the pen drive removed...

Comment: @Calmarius: Sorry, but no I can't. It was somewhere on MSDN that seems to have been edited in the ~2.5 years since. I probably need to rewrite this answer (and Microsoft really needs to modify GetDriveType too). With things like hot-swappable disks, the dividing line between "fixed" and "removable" disks isn't clear like it once was, and I'm not entirely sure what rules they follow now.

Comment: USB flash drives, HDDs, etc. definitely have `PhysicalDriveN`, and you can create multiple volumes on them (maybe not via Disk Management UI).

Answer (score 2):

It's C#.Net code, but this is what i've written to do the job:

```
using System.Management; //Add in a reference to this as well in the project settings
public static string GetPhysicalDevicePath(char DriveLetter)
{
    ManagementClass devs = new ManagementClass( @"Win32_Diskdrive");
    {
        ManagementObjectCollection moc = devs.GetInstances();
        foreach(ManagementObject mo in moc)
        {
            foreach (ManagementObject b in mo.GetRelated("Win32_DiskPartition"))
            {
                foreach (ManagementBaseObject c in b.GetRelated("Win32_LogicalDisk"))
                {
                    string DevName = string.Format("{0}", c["Name"]);
                    if (DevName[0] == DriveLetter)
                        return string.Format("{0}", mo["DeviceId"]); 
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```